# how do I assign an empty string to an attribute

Tags: jquery

This doesn't take into account alternative or error cases. If there is no alt attribute from which to grab, then the main image will contain the previous image's alt text. I want to clear out that alt text by assigning an empty string to that attribute, e.g. `attr.alt = (not_undefined) ? thumb.attr() : '';`

How do I do this?

```
$(function() {
$('.component-individual-detail-profile').each(function() {
    var imgContainer = $(this).find('.photos');

    imgContainer.find('li').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var thumb = $(this).find('img');
        var attributes = {
            src: thumb.attr('src')
        };

        if (typeof thumb.attr('alt') !== 'undefined') {
            attributes.alt = thumb.attr('alt');
        }
        if (typeof thumb.attr('title') !== 'undefined') {
            attributes.title = thumb.attr('title');
        }
        imgContainer.find('.selected').attr(attributes);
    });
});

});
```

Comment: Just declare your `attributes` variable like that : `var attributes = {src: thumb.attr('src'), alt:'',title:''};`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
thumb.attr('alt', '')
```

The `attr()` method is a getter when used with one parameter. It becomes a setter when used with two parameters, the first being the attribute name and the second the value to set. In that case, an empty string is used.

Comment: I'm running into an issue with this method. using `thumb.attr('alt', '')` will result in `<img src="foo" alt>` and not the expected `<img src="foo" alt="">`. The latter is preferred for images that are purely decorative ("Mark up purely decorative images so they can be ignored by assistive technology by using an empty alt attribute (alt="")." ref: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#alt)